# How to find or calculate 30-day constant maturity price of a future?

Tags: futures, vix

Question, pretty much says it.  Is there a reliable place where this data can be found or, if not, is there a reliable place where the underlying data needed to *calculate* the constant maturity price could be found?

Many thanks.

Comment: You have to linearly interpolate between two futures, one with maturity less than a month (the nearby VIX future) and one with maturity greater than a month (the second nearby). Documents about VIX ETFs explain this calculation in detail with examples. The Vix futures trade on the CFE/CBOE exchange.

Comment: It is all explained [here](us.spindices.com/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-vix-future-index.pdf?force_download=true)

Comment: The updated link to the mentioned doc: https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-vix-futures-indices.pdf